# HowTo: Binding between Vis.js graph network and REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am beginner in Angular and JavaScript. I have network graph created by vis.js. I would like to dynamically update labels of edges and nodes.

Labels for edges and nodes are provided by server (json).

For exmaple:
Graph is represented by:

```
var nodes = [
   {"id": 1, "group": "A", "label": ""},
   {"id": 2, "group": "B", "label": ""}
]

var edges = [{"from": 1, "to": 2, "label": ""}]
```

Server REST API is:

```
 127.0.0.1/nodes/1/
 {"label": "node 1"}


 127.0.0.1/nodes/2/
 {"label": "node 2"}


 127.0.0.1/edges/1/2/
 {"label": " edge 1 -> 2"}
```

So how to do dynamic binding between server and graph? I would like use Angular, but if you see some easier way feel free with your answer.

Thanks for advice

P.S. I know here is a project Angular-visjs , but it is under development. So I would like to avoid this.